# Async/Await and Web API blocks execution

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

I have the following in my REST API server(using OWIN):

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(Session))]
    [Route("api/v1/async")]
    public Session async_status()
    {
        AsyncStatus();
        return new Session() {...};
    }

    private async Task<int> AsyncStatus()
    {
        await SyncMethod();
        return 42;
    }

    private Task<int> SyncMethod()
    {
        CopyFileThatTakesALongTime(....);
        // OR
        Thread.Sleep(60000);
        return Task.FromResult(42);
    }
```

Why dies it block and the client does not get the desired asynchronous-ness. I I would expect that when calling:

```
await SyncMethod();
```

The caller would be freed and unblocked while the rest of the sleep would be executed. What am i missing?

P.S: I can easily fix it by replacing this:

```
AsyncStatus();
```

With:

```
Task.Run(() => AsyncStatus() );
```

The reason i am not doing that is because of this reading:

> > https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html

In other words if it's bad to use Task.Run() in a web server as in the above article but you can't use async/await, what is the solution?

Comment: Are you trying to simulate calling some blocking API from an asynchronous code? First of all, async should propagate to the top of the call stack (so you should have your controller's public method marked as async and doing await on the async calls). Second, using Thread.Sleep should be avoided at all costs. In async world it's replaced by "await Task.Delay(...)"

Comment: Seems like you're trying to "fire and forget". Read [this](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html).

Comment: Everything is fare Api controller is public

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish with this code.  It looks like you are mixing the concepts of Tasks (coroutines) with Threads.  Those are two very different approaches to multitasking in software.  Using await Task.Delay(...) will fix the SyncMethod to be async complian (but i wouldn't then call it sync method).  Finally, the async_status() method fires and forgets so nothing would suspend in that method anyway.  Can you provide more context to what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: What i am trying to accomplish is very simple. Let's take a real example. Say you want to develop an API that would instruct the server to copy big files from place A to B. You don't want the call to be blocking but just fire the copy and that's it. One of the other requirement is the ability afterwards to know the progress of the copy, but let's not deal with that part for now.

Comment: Then I would follow the link posted by Gabriel Luci above.

Comment: That link is not relevant to my use case as it relies on IIS , I am using OWIN which i believe does not have recycling background tasks

Comment: Sounds like you need to implement proper background processing in your app. That could take the form of a [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) job, or perhaps use a message queue such as RabbitMQ or Azure Service Bus to fire off a message to an external app, which would then process the job, and would then notify the web app that it's finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `async` method only becomes asynchronous when asynchronous work starts.

That is, all of your code will run synchronously until something truly asynchronous *starts*. Once some truly asynchronous work starts, a `Task` is returned up the call stack, which then can be awaited (or not) by the calling methods.

The implication of this is that an async method could still hold up the request if you're doing a lot of synchronous work before the asynchronous work. Your example shows that perfectly. Let's break down exactly what a thread is doing:

1. Start running `async_status()`
2. Jump to `AsyncStatus()`
3. At `await SyncMethod()` the thread jumps to `SyncMethod()`.
4. The thread halts at `Thread.Sleep(60000)` for 60 seconds.
5. `SyncMethod()` returns a complete `Task`.
6. Because there is nothing to await, `AsyncStatus()` continues synchronously and returns a value.
7. `async_status()` returns and thus the request.

`Thread.Sleep(60000)` can be replaced with any processor-intensive task (or any long-running non-async task) and the result would be the same if it happens before the first `await` in that method.

This is also described in Microsoft's documentation under the heading [What happens in an async method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model#BKMK_WhatHappensUnderstandinganAsyncMethod). Notice point 3:

> 3. Something happens in `GetStringAsync` that suspends its progress. Perhaps it must wait for a website to download or some other blocking activity. To avoid blocking resources, `GetStringAsync` yields control to its caller, `AccessTheWebAsync`.

Control only returns to the calling method *when a `Task` is returned*, which only happens when an asynchronous task is actually started. In your example, there isn't any asynchronous task happening. If you added one (even just `await Task.Delay(1)`) you would see different results. For example, this will return right away:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Session))]
[Route("api/v1/async")]
public Session async_status()
{
    AsyncStatus();
    return new Session() {...};
}

private async Task<int> AsyncStatus()
{
    await SyncMethod();
    return 42;
}

private async Task<int> SyncMethod()
{
    await Task.Delay(1);
    Thread.Sleep(60000);
    return 42;
}
```

At `await Task.Delay(1)` (or any *truly* asynchronous work):

1. `SyncMethod()` returns an incomplete `Task` to `AsyncStatus()`
2. `AsyncStatus()` returns an incomplete `Task` to `async_status()`.
3. That `Task` is not awaited, so execution of `async_status()` continues

**To answer your question:**

You asked:

> if it's bad to use Task.Run() in a web server as in the above article but you can't use async/await, what is the solution?

You mentioned the [Task.Run Etiquette](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html) article. Read his conclusion at the end:

> Do not use it just to “provide something awaitable for my async method to use”.

Your purpose here is not to just "provide something awaitable", but to start a background job and not make the client wait until it's done. That's different.

So yes, you could actually use `Task.Run()`. However, as noted in Stephen Cleary's [Fire and Forget on ASP.NET](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html) article, the problem with doing it this way is that ASP.NET does not keep track of that background task. So if it's long-running, then recycling the app pool could immediately kill that work. His article describes better methods of performing background work that you don't want to hold up the return of the request.

Comment: Even if i replace the sleep with a very long for loop, it will return to the caller only after the loop is complete.

Comment: Actually, that really explains the example in your question too... I should update my answer to be more clear.

Comment: You updated your answer but it's not what i meant, i meant that you would put the foreach you added in the in the SyncMethod()(not in the AsyncStatus), then i would expect the await SyncMethod() in AsyncStatus to return the control to the caller because of the await as you said. Note that i tested it and it behaves as idescribed such that the control is not returned to the caller after the await.

Comment: I updated my answer to be more clear. Even if the loop is in `SyncMethod()`, the result will be the same if the loop is before the first `await` in `SyncMethod()`. My answer describes why.

Comment: Why are you saying on 3. that the await will jump to sync method and block the whole thread, isn't the whole point of await that it waits and releases the caller?

Comment: `SyncMethod()` still needs to run and return `Task` before it can be awaited. Control only returns to the calling method when something actually asynchronous is started. I updated my answer with a link to some Microsoft documentation.

Comment: If the loop is in SyncMethod then it's after the first await since the whole SyncMeothd is being awaitedin AsyncStatus, so why the control is not returned to the caller.

Comment: By the way pasting here from your link:
"Pay close attention to the await operator. It suspends AccessTheWebAsync;

AccessTheWebAsync can't continue until getStringTask is complete.
Meanwhile, control returns to the caller of AccessTheWebAsync."

This means exactly what i am expecting that control is return to async_status when SyncMethod is awaited

Comment: I reworded my answer to make it clearer. The method still has to run and return *something* before control goes back to the calling method, even if it's an incomplete `Task`. In your example, nothing actually asynchronous happens, so at no point can an incomplete `Task` get returned until all the waiting is already done.

Comment: Thx a lot for the effort but your answer is still unclear to me why is the AsyncStatus in my code is not behaving like the GetStringAsync from the doc you pasted? In other words do you have a code that would show the asynchronousness, any code so i can try it and prove your point?

Comment: So, yes, "control returns to the caller of AccessTheWebAsync" at the `await`, but that's also true of `getStringTask` (which is a call to `client.GetStringAsync`): control only returns to `AccessTheWebAsync` when `client.GetStringAsync()` returns a `Task` (when it starts its asynchronous work).

Comment: Upvoted for the great effort, unfortunately i can't mark it as the accepted answer as it does not answer the question.

Comment: In your example, `async_status()` cannot continue until `AsyncStatus()` returns a `Task`, and it cannot return a `Task` until `SyncMethod()` returns  a `Task`, which only happens after `Thread.Sleep()`.

Comment: You can test this by making `SyncMethod()` `async` and adding `await Task.Delay(1)` before the `Thread.Sleep(60000)`. I added this code to my answer with an explanation of why it's different.

Comment: I also updated my answer to actually answer the question "what is the solution?"

Comment: @isaac.hazan: This is the correct answer. To summarize: [`await` first examines its awaitable, and if it is already complete, then the `async` method just continues synchronously](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). You can change `Thread.Sleep` to `await Task.Delay` to see how the code would behave if you changed it to be actually asynchronous.

Comment: @StephenCleary Why does it still wait if in case i replace the Thread.Sleep() with a very long for loop or even a copy to a file?

Comment: @isaac.hazan I think I confused you with the first version of my answer, I'm sorry. I originally said that an `async` method will run synchronously until the first `await`, but that is only partially true. The whole truth is that `await` can't do anything until a `Task` is returned. If you look at the source code for something *truly* asynchronous, like `Task.Delay`, you'll see that it returns a `DelayPromise`, which derives from `Task`. *After* that is returned, `await` can do its job and pause execution of the method and return control to the calling method.

Comment: The source code for `Task.Delay` is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/e468cd3c45a1057cf649056ba61dacc99c7fa546/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L5484).

Comment: So in your code, the only time a `Task` is returned is after all the waiting is complete. Even if you replace `Thread.Sleep` with a loop or copying a file, it will be busy doing that and not returning a `Task`, so there is nothing for `await` to do. You can test what I am saying with the block of code in my answer. You can put `Task.Delay(1)` pretty much anywhere before the `Thread.Sleep` (or a big loop, or copying a file) and it will work as you expect - because `Task.Delay` will return a `Task` *before* the work is done.

Comment: So maybe i am confused, isn't the whole point of await to return the control to the caller regardless of the operation being done? Which operations will cause await to return the control and which will not?

Comment: Not "regardless of the operation being done", no. It's for asynchronous operations. The `await` keyword can only act on a `Task`. If there is no `Task`, it can't do anything. So it has to wait until the method you called returns a `Task`.

Comment: Look at the source code for `Task.Delay` that I linked to above. It returns a `DelayPromise` *before* the work is done (the timer in this case). At that point, `await` can do its job.